# Access a function from a Component in another Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am totally blank on how to use a function that is inside a component and needs to be used in another component.

Here is a simple program:

**Test.js**

```
export default function Test(){
  const testFunc = () => {
   console.log("it is working")
}
return(
  <div>
   Hi
</div>
)
}
```

**Test2.js**

```
export default function Test2(){
  
return(
  <button onClick={}> // Here I want to use testFunc() from Test file
   Click
</button>
)
}
```

Could someone please explain how can it be achieved to access the function in Test2 file.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the relation between these components? Do they have the same parent?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Parent will be App.js file, so yes the parent are same

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, Oh my, is there any way to achieve this, I want to write reusable function but the problem I am facing I am unable to use hooks since it is throwing error that hooks can be used only in react components, so no other way, I thought writing that reusable function inside a component.

Comment: *it is throwing error that hooks can be used only in react components* - please show the code that throws that error

Comment: @KonradLinkowski **React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooks** --- This is the error I am getting

Comment: can you share the code where you're getting this error? I posted two ways you can try to solve your issue. one is to pass it down from a parent component, the second is to use a custom hook.

Comment: You can use context to achieve exactly what you want, but you would know all of this if you would read the documentation.

Comment: @elguapo, Sorry it is in another device, which is for the company's purpose. The error was shown when I tried writing the function in a common.js file (Where all reusable functions are placed), but for my purpose, I need of using hooks, so when I tried to add them, the above-mentioned error was shown.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to pass the function as a prop to the child component. You can't or I should say shouldn't pass a prop to a parent, you can do this but is not a react way and never recommended. What you would do in this case is but the logic in the parent because both siblings are needing access to it.

```
const App = () => {
    const clickHandler = () => {
        alert("Click event")
    }
 return (
    <div className="App">
        <ChildOne clickHandler={clickHandler}/>
        <ChildTwo clickHandler={clickHandler}/>
    </div>
 )
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can either pass it down from a parent component, shown below, or you can use a custom hook

Parent Component:

```
import Child from './Child.js'
export default function Parent() {
  
  const functionToBePassed = () => { ... }

  return (
    <Child func={functionToBePassed}>
  )
}
```

Or you can do it via a custom hook

Two files, first one is the hook

```
export default function useFunc() {
  const functionToBeShared = () => {...}

  return { functionToBeShared }
}

//this is any component that wants to use the hook
import useFunc from ./useFunc;
export default function ComponentThatUsesHook() {
  const {functionToBeShared} = useFunc();
}
```

Comment: I think using a custom hook method looks possible because the first method may end up importing all the child components to one place which may result in huge amount of code.

Comment: you don't need to worry too much about optimization at the start, if you run into performance problems later you can find ways to fix it but React does a pretty good job at solving these issues from the beginning

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the React community.

`To use a function that is inside a component and needs to be used in another component.`

You need a common parent, that handles the function.

Let's say you have the following structure.

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
    return <>
        <Test1 />
        <Test2 />
    <>
}
```

If you want some function in Test1 to affect Test2, then you do what in react is called lifting state up https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

`ParentComponent`

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    return <>
        <Test1 setValue={setValue} />
        <Test2 value={value} />
    <>
}
```

`Test1`

```
export const Test1 = (props) => {
    return <>
        <input onChange={(e) => props.setValue(e.target.vale} />
    <>
}
```

`Test2`

```
export const Test2 = (props) => {
    return <p>{props.value}</p> 
}
```

When a component renders another component, it is called the parent of the rendered child. Imagine React as a tree data structure where the `App.tsx/jsx` will be the tree's root.

Inspecting the code above, we can see that we have a function held in the parent. This is the function you would probably consider putting in `Test1`. However, if you need to use it in another component, that is not a child of the current element. You will need to find the nearest common parent and pass the functionality down like in the example above.

I hope it makes sense. If not, I recommend glancing at the Main Concepts part of the official React documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks for this bud, definitely I will take a look into this.

Answer (score 2):

As Konrad said in the comments, this can't be possible since these 2 components lack no relationship (Neither Components are rendering or calling each other within)

Something you could do is Render the `Test2.js` component within `Test.js` and add a callback like so:

Test.js

```js
import Test2 from '...';

export default function Test(){
  const testFunc = () => {
   console.log("it is working")
}


return(
  <div>
   Hi
   <Test2 callbackProp={testFunc} />
</div>
)
}
```

Test2.js

```js
export default function Test2({callbackProp}){
  
return(
  <button onClick={() => {callbackProp();} }> // Here I want to use testFunc() from Test file
   Click
</button>
)
}
```

Now whenever Test.js is rendered, it will also render Test2 (Since Test is rendering a Test2 Component) but whenever you click the button within Test2, it will execute the callback which is a function passed from Test

Nonetheless though, it's impossible to call any functions from another Component without passing down a prop like this (for future reference)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Usually, context is used to share the same state between many components that aren't in parent-children relations.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-monad-lcy4rz?file=/src/App.js)

### Creating context

First, create a context:

```
const MyContext = createContext();
```

And context provider:

```
const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ myState, setMyState }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And context hook (for convenience):

```
const useMyContext = () => useContext(MyContext);
```

### Using context

Remember to use the provider in the common ancestor of the components:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <MyContextProvider>
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
    </MyContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Create your components:

```
function Component1() {
  // as you can see, you can access the function here
  const { setMyState } = useMyContext();
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setMyState((state) => state + 1)}>click me</button>
  );
}

function Component2() {
  // and the value here
  const { myState } = useMyContext();
  return myState;
}
```